# 2 ways SSL with CURL PHP not working

Tags: php, ssl, curl

In SOAPUI, I import the .pfx file in SSL setting only, then I test the API methods and it works without issues. Now, I want to implement the same working sample in SOAPUI to my PHP application. SO, I used CURL PHP to manage it. What I did is basically, I import the same cert that I used in SOAP UI to my PHP file. I want to access the protected server with my public key using my private key.

**UPDATE: 29 June 2018**

PFX file: test-cert.pfx

```
 $url = 'https://domain.com.ph/api/id_num';

    $headers = array(
                    "Content-Type: application/json",
                    "token really_long_numbers",
                    );

    $curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url );        
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT , 443);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 2);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/d/client.pem");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/d/key.pem");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, "******");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/d/cacert.pem");
```

I tried to generate CA from PFX, using the command below

`openssl pkcs12 -in test-cert.pfx -out test-cert.pem -clcerts`

AND /OR

`openssl pkcs12 -in test-cert.pfx -out test-cert.pem -clcerts -nodes`

The new error is now

> cURL Error #:SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer
>   certificate

**UPDATE: 2 July 2018**

I already added the following line to the php.ini file and, of course, downloaded the cacert.pem file from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

[curl]
; A default value for the CURLOPT_CAINFO option. This is required to be an
; absolute path.

```
curl.cainfo="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/openssl/certs/cacert.pem"
openssl.cafile="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/openssl/certs/cacert.pem"
```

My php.ini configuration file is located

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

and added the line below in curl

CURLOPT_CAINFO => '/path/to/my/exported/cacert.pem'

CURLOPT_CAPATH => '/path/to/my/exported/cacert.pem'

I also enable the following lines `php_openssl.dll` and `mod_ssl` in apache configuration and php.ini

Lastly, I downloaded the ca-bundle.crt in `cacert.pem` location too.

**still it didn't work.**

Answer (score 1):

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT , 443);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 2);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, getcwd() . "/my_cert.pem");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, getcwd() . "/my_key.pem");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/cacert.pem");
```

You need to specify all 3 - your private key (SSLKEY), your public certificate (SSLCERT) and the certificate authority chain (CAINFO) up to the root CA.
The key and certificates should be in plain-text PEM format instead of PFX

`openssl pkcs12 -in test-cert.pfx -out test-cert.pem -nodes`

### UPDATE: 29 June 2018

Download http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem (or https://github.com/bagder/ca-bundle/blob/e9175fec5d0c4d42de24ed6d84a06d504d5e5a09/ca-bundle.crt which also conatins RSA-1024 certificates) into `/Applications/AMPPS/extra/etc/openssl/certs/cacert.pem`
Then update `php.ini` and restart Apache

```
[curl]
; A default value for the CURLOPT_CAINFO option. This is required to be an
; absolute path.
curl.cainfo="/Applications/AMPPS/extra/etc/openssl/certs/cacert.pem"
openssl.cafile="/Applications/AMPPS/extra/etc/openssl/certs/cacert.pem"
```

Comment: One extra note: The chain must contain all intermediate certificates, not only the root CA.

Comment: Actually, it may contain only the intermediate certificate - if it is a well-known and trusted authority (and so the remote side could be reasonably expected to have it inside its CA bundle). But it depends on the particular case.

Comment: Of course, you are right, the root CA most probably should already be in the local certificate storage

Comment: @IVOGELOV after carefully follow your instructions, it still didn't worked. The solutions I've tried are 
1. I insert the CERT/Public the one that starts -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
2. I insert the SSLCERT/Private the one that starts -----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----  3. I create CA cert using this `openssl pkcs12 -in test-cert.pfx -cacerts -nokeys -chain -out cacerts.crt` and import in CAINFO. The result is `unable to set private key file: dapskey.pem' type PEM ` please see updated code above

Comment: Are you sure that the PEM files are in the same directory as the script ? If not - then instead of `getcwd()` use the full pathname of each file. Also confirm that the `ca.crt` is in plain-text PEM format.

Comment: @IVOGELOV CURLE_SSL_CACERT (60)

Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates.

Comment: @IVOGELOV may I know if whos going to provide CA for my public and private keys? Do I need to create one for this or I need to create CA using these keys?

Comment: This error means that your CA-bundle (the one that you downloaded from HAXX) is not properly installed. If the above settings in PHP are not working (please confirm with `phpinfo()`) - you can try either manually providing the CURLOPT_CAINFO with the HAXX file or set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, to FALSE. As a last resort - you can play with CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, e.g. 1, 2 or 3.